F# foldBack conversion to tail recursive function
For learning purposes I've emulated List.foldBack. The emulated version is head-recursive.
Is there an elegant way to convert it to the tail-recursive version?
let li : int list = [1;2;3]

let rec foldBack f li initialValue = 
    match li with
    | [] -> initialValue
    | x::xs -> f x (foldBack f xs initialValue)

let resultFoldBack = 
    foldBack (fun x initValue -> x::initValue) li []
resultFoldBack |> printfn "Result for the emulated foldBack: %A"


Sure. We just reverse it first in a loop, then fold it on the way back. In pseudocode,
foldBack f li z0 = g1 li []
  where
  g1 [a;b;c;...;m] acc = g1 [b;c;...;m] (a::acc)
  g1 [] acc = g2 acc z0
  g2 [m;l;k;...;a] z0 = g2 [l;k;...;a] (f m z0)
  g2 [] res = res

This is actually just two folds one after the other,
foldBack f li z0 = fold f (fold g li []) z0
  where
  g x acc = x::acc

or even just fold f (reverse li) z0 right away. The reverse is not in tail position, but it doesn't really matter since the call stack's depth is just a constant, 2.
Some might suggest "continuation-passing style", but that's just building the same list-in-reverse, just inside the anonymous functions' chain of closures' stored environment frames instead of the linked list nodes:
foldBack f li z0 = g1 li ident
  where
  ident x = x
  g1 [a;b;c;...;m] ret = g1 [b;c;...;m] (acc => ret (f a acc))
  g1 [] ret = ret z0

This is of course also just a fold, building a function as an accumulated value, which is finally applied to calculate the result:
foldBack f li z0 = (fold h li (x => x)) z0
  where
  h b ret = (acc => ret (f b acc))
            (*   { ret + {f b} }   *)

As an illustration, for a three-element list, the final ret application will be
let ret1 := (acc => ident (f a acc))    (* a at the bottom *)
let ret2 := (acc => ret1  (f b acc))
let ret3 := (acc => ret2  (f c acc))    (* c at the top *)
ret3 z0

expressing the application
(acc => (acc => (acc => (x => x)
                        (f a acc))      (* a at the bottom *)
                (f b acc))
        (f c acc)) z0                   (* c at the top *)

and this will cause the calculation of
let acc := z0
let acc := f c acc
let acc := f b acc
let x   := f a acc
x

which is effectively equivalent to the unwinding of the stack with g2 in the first version, calculating
f a (f b (f c z0))

straight from the inside-out, having built the function to do that, on the way in.
But really it's no different than reversing the list and then processing the reversed list as an explicit data structure - as long as there are no opportunities for parallel / concurrent processing, a linear calculation is just a linear calculation.
The real difference is with the partial applications,
{f x} = (acc => f x acc)

it's how we are creating them - as dumb lambda functions or as active computational objects able to be run concurrently and do some work on x before receiving that acc, perhaps.
But CPS in itself is not magic. Whether we put those xs - or the partial applications {f x} - into cons cells or environment frames is less of an issue. Unless of course the nature of f lets us re-arrange the computational structure from linear to something clever.

"Some might suggest continuation-passing style..."  I will just show myself out...

After some struggle with understanding how continuation-passing style works in practice, I've come up with a solution. The diagram of the recursive calls helps to understand what actually is going on with the computation in the base case.
let foldBack f li initialValue =
    let rec loop k list = 
        match list with
        | [] -> k initialValue
        | x::xs -> loop (fun init -> k (f x init)) xs
    loop id li


let resultFoldBack = 
    foldBack (fun x init -> x::init) [1;2;3] []
resultFoldBack |> printfn "Result for the emulated tail-recursive foldBack with continuations: %A"
// output: [1; 2; 3]


(* the diagram of the recursive calls of the tail-recursive foldBack with continuations

-> foldBack (fun x init -> x::init) [1;2;3] []
-> loop id [1;2;3]
-> loop (fun init -> id (1::init)) [2;3]
-> loop (fun init -> (fun init -> id (1::init)) (2::init)) [3]
-> loop (fun init -> (fun init -> (fun init -> id (1::init)) (2::init)) (3::init)) []
-> (fun init -> (fun init -> (fun init -> id (1::init)) (2::init)) (3::init)) []
-> (fun init -> (fun init -> id (1::init)) (2::init)) [3]
-> (fun init -> id (1::init)) [2;3]
-> id [1;2;3]
[1;2;3]
*)


SO says that F# converts tail recursive calls into loops. so it stays at the same level. I updated your diagram. Cheers. :) (I just saw your answer here right now.)

the "init" parameter is IMO much better named "result", "result_so_far", "partial_result" etc. the point is it's not initial value, it is "almost-complete result". the recursion hypothesis for "loop k xs" is that loop's action is to feed the full result for xs  to k . thus for xs=[] we call k initValue and for xs=(x::ys) we 1. need to call loop k2 ys, 2. we know the result for ys will be fed to k2, so 3. this k2 will receive this partial result, so we define k2 result = so we need to update this result to include x thus creating the more complete result, which we MUST

... must feed to the k we've received as the argument - to fulfill the recursion hypothesis for loop! thus closing the "recursion definition loop" so to speak -- we write recursive code under assumption that it works, and then must make sure that it indeed does! :) thus k2 result = k (x::result).

3/3 or in general, k2 result = k (f x result). this also means that k2 = k + {f x} in shorthand notation, with {f x} standing for the partially applied f, i.e. (fun v -> f x v), and + for functional composition, where {f + g}(x) = f(g(x)). It is usually written as small circle in the middle, in math,  {f ∘ g}(x) = f(g(x)).

so it goes like loop [1;2;3] id -> loop [2;3] {id+{1::}} -> loop [3] {{id+{1::}}+{2::}} -> loop [] {{{id+{1::}}+{2::}}+{3::}} -> {{{id+{1::}}+{2::}}+{3::}} [] -> {{id+{1::}}+{2::}} [3::[]] -> {id+{1::}} [2::[3]] -> id [1::[2,3]] -> [1,2,3]. this way it might be easier to follow.
